# How to have one catkin workspace rely on another

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a generally accepted way to handle the case where I have some libraries that are generated in one catkin workspace and are used by a project in another catkin workspace?

What I mean by handle is, how do I tell the project workspace where to find the libraries generated by the library workspace?

I can imagine lots of ways to do this using symbolic links and/or environment variables but they all seem somewhat fragile or messy. I'm wondering if anyone has a way of doing this that they like.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224058/how-to-have-one-catkin-workspace-rely-on-another/) by [gabehein](https://answers.ros.org/users/22175/gabehein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you want is called [chaining catkin workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces).

The technique is described in [that tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0